# Empty grammar in WADL (Jersey)

Tags: java, ant, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am developing a server using Jersey JAX-RS. When I access the application WADL, it contains the description of all operations, but no reference to the XML schema (the grammar element is empty).

Here is a simplified version of what I have.
XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="parent" type="Parent" />
<xsd:complexType name="Parent">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="son" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Here a .java for handling requests, the class Parent is generated by JAXB automatic generation. *The code compiles and handle requests just fine, if there are syntax errors it's just because I reproduced a minimal portion of the code.*

```
@Path("/parents")
public class ParentAPI {
    private static ObjectFactory jaxbOf = new ObjectFactory();

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "getParent")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    @Path("/{name}")
    public JAXBElement<Parent> getParent(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        //.....
        return jaxbOf.createParent(parent);
    }

    @POST
    @ApiOperation(value = "postParent")
    @ApiResponses(
            value = { @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created"), @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request"),
                    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response postNode(JAXBElement<Parent> jaxbParent, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        Parent parent = jaxbParent.getValue();
        //.....

        UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        URI u = builder.path(parent.getName()).build();
        return Response.created(u).build();

    }
}
```

I am using JAXBElement<> wrapper because I have named complexTypes in the schema. Moreover, I am using a validator implementing `MessageBodyReader<JAXBElement<?>`.

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Example</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>io.swagger.jaxrs.listing, it.example</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/Example/rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now, I tried to expose the xsd putting it into the WebContent, but still no luck, and it does not appear in the WADL (autogenerated). I am compiling and packaging using ANT.

I searched carefully in other questions, someone have no answer, others are old and suggests solutions using Servlet library I don't have (and I can't add, because it is an assignment and we have a set of libraries we can use), and looks like in Jersey the schema should be in the WADL by default, so I really can't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I am using named complex types, that leads me to use JAXBElement<> wrappers and so on.
Eliminating the named complex types, the problem was solved.